# Powershell crashing between "Running" and "Failed" states

Tags: powershell

Just wondering if any of you ever encountered this issue as it is driving me nuts.

After I bring up Powershell ISE on my work laptop and press ENTER a couple of times OR run the debugger a couple of times, the commandline changes from PS C:> to PS>, and on my next run of the debugger, [the status below keeps alternating between "Failed" and "Running Script" like a maniac.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRhMG.jpg)

I have tried launching it as administrator without success. Has anybody ever come across this issue?

Comment: Sadly, the screenshot isn't very helpful, the transition from "Running" to "Failed" happens too quickly to even be read.  Based on my research, "Failed" is a result of an exception being thrown, so I suspect the script is partially at fault.  Are you able to create an example script and reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Ramhound That is in fact the symptom that I wanted to show in the gif. Usually the state is either Failed or Running, however in this case the ISE seems to be in some kind of funk. The issue happens with any script, in fact I have just placed "test" inside a script and ran the script from the ISE for about 10 consecutive times and ended up with the same issue.

Comment: Any script?  PowerShell 5.1 or PowerShell 6.x?

Answer (score 0):

<s>The solution to this was as inane as removing Powershell from the optional features menu in Windows, rebooting the pc and re-enabling it afterwards. Stupid, but it worked.</s>

EDIT: The correct solution in fact was to use Powershell (x86), rather than the 64-bit version, despite running 64-bit Windows 10.